# Excel Radar chart to visualize data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a set of data with which I want to produce a Radar chart for easy comparison.

[image: the data]

This is just like an inventory list with A,B and C as the products list, I want to achieve the following :

Compare the columns - *dynamic range*, *mono or color* , *usb3 or usb 2 and price* in a **RADAR CHART**

Comment: I watched that and it was a good tutorial , but only if someone could explain how can we deal with the kind of situation I am in. How do I rate lets say Global : 10 and Rolling as 1 in my case. ( Please see the snapshot )

Comment: You might get a better response if you explained just a little bit better what result you want to get.  Maybe even draw something in Paint.

Comment: I have edited the question to more easier and comprehensible one. All I want is to have a product comparison chart to visualize, I don't know how to get one.